# FM-index - print all patterns

Tags: algorithms, strings, pattern-recognition

How is it possible to print all patterns of length $k$ contained in a string, using the FM-index and Burrows-Wheeler transform?

PROBLEM DETAIL:
The input I have is:

- the text encoded with the Burrows-Wheeler Transform
- the data structure of the FM-Index.

In particularly for the second element listed, I have:

- $C(c)$ is a table that, for each character $c$ in the alphabet,
  contains the number of occurrences of lexically smaller characters in
  the text
- $Occ(c, k)$  is the number of occurrences of character $c$ in
  the prefix of the Burrows-Wheeler transform $1..k$

The only strategy that I've found at the moment is to reconstruct the text from the Burrows-Wheeler transform and, during that operation, for every char print the pattern that starts from it. In pseudocode,

```
---------------------------------------------
DATA
---------------------------------------------

bwt[n]  => burrow wheeler transform of the text
C, Occ => FM-index data structure
K => lenght of the patterns to be extracted (so extract all patterns of length k from text T)

---------------------------------------------
Algorithm
---------------------------------------------

n = |bwt|; //text length
T[0,n]; //array used to save the original text 
T[--n] = bwt[0]; //first char of the original text

currentIndex = 0;

for i = 0 to |btw(T)| - 1 do
    //get original 
    lastFirst = c(bwt[currentIndex]) + Occ(bwt[currentIndex], currentIndex);
    T[--n] = bwt[lastFirst];
    currentIndex = lastFirst;

    //print pattern only if we have reconstructed at least k char 
    if((|btw(T)| - n) >= k) from original text
        print T[n, n+k]; //print last k char reconstructed
    endif;
endfor;
```

Is there a better technique or strategy to solve the problem? Is there a strategy that doesn't need to reconstruct the original text?

Comment: Hi @Raphael, i updated my question with more detail. Do you think you can help me? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to print every substring of length $k$ from the original text. To do this you will need to invert the Burrows-Wheeler transform completely at some point, which is indeed what you do in your pseudocode. One improvement for your method would be to just store the $k$ latest characters instead of storing the whole string.

Your method is already as good as it gets, as it is equivalent to doing one pass over the string and directly printing the substrings, which is the minimum you have to do in any case.

--

Edit: so we want to print each substring only once. Now the problem becomes more interesting. An easy solution is to store the substrings in a hash map, for example, and thus avoid printing duplicates. If you can afford storing the original string and the inverse suffix array, then there is a sophisticated solution available which is good if $k$ is small.

A basic operation on the FM index is a left extension of a string. If we know the range of suffixes in the suffix array that start with the string $\alpha$, we can compute in constant time the range of $w\alpha$ for any character $w$. Here's how. Let $(i,j)$ be the range of the string $\alpha$. The range of $w \alpha$ is:

$$(C[w] + occ(w, i - 1) + 1,\;\; C[w] + occ(w,j)) \;.$$

We can start with the range of an empty string, which is $(1, n)$, and do a depth-first search of left-extensions down to a depth of $k$. At depth $k$ we will print the substring corresponding to the current range. For this we need to have the original string and the inverse suffix array $ISA$, which is defined by $ISA[SA[i]] = i$, where $SA$ is the suffix array. The substring corresponding to the range $(i,j)$ is the first $k$ characters of the suffix $ISA[i]$.

This method is very efficient in practice if $k$ is small, as it often is in bioinformatics applications. For a more thorough explanation on the backwards search I recommend e.g. this blog post: http://alexbowe.com/fm-index/

Comment: Hi @jnalanko, thank you for your answer.I hope we're right! :) My only hesitation is that in this way if you have the same pattern multiple time in the same string, it will be printed out more than once (the problem is not clear about this point, and doesn't specify if every pattern found must be printed out only 1 time or more)

Comment: Thank you for the other details @jnalanko. Let me see if I understood correctly: what you're naming as left extension is what i name Last to First mapping, and it's used for backward search (I already read also the blog post that you linked ;))

Comment: So your advice is: start with empty string and go for all possible combination of char contained in string, and so on recursively (or in other way) to find all the possible patterns. Then convert the various indexes found for every pattern using ISA and the original text. One question: if a backward search for one of the various combination bring to a range of index that contains a duplicate pattern, is there a method to identify them using some property of fm-index or i have to check them manually?

Comment: A range contains all occurrences of a pattern. We only print the first occurrence in the range.